# OracleDB unified_audit_trail additional_info

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle19c, oracle21c

How to add additional_info to unified audit records?

There is column additional_info but i cant find anywhere how to use it.

I cant find any procedure or option to set it.

Will this additional_info be in syslog if i set audit to go to syslog?

Answer (score 0):

> How to add additional_info to unified audit records?

There does not appear to be any way to set or alter audit trail content directly (that would sort of defeat the purpose of an audit trail).

> Will this additional_info be in syslog if i set audit to go to syslog?

No. Per the documentation, the `additional_info` column is not included in the syslog: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/dbseg/administering-the-audit-trail.html#GUID-3EFB75DB-AE1C-44E6-B46E-30E5702B0FC4